# MySQL: count number of rows returned by a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, procedure

I want to Insert the records returned by procedure in to temporary table in another procedure

I have a Procedure Like Below

```
    call getName()
```

Now I want to Check whether the above procedure is returning records or not.

I want to do this in another procedure. So I am trying to insert the records returned from  getName() procedure in to temp table in another procedure to carry out count operation.

Let me know how to count no of rows returned by one procedure in another procedure.

Comment: What is the purpose behind these stored procedures?  You may be suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have a search Result Page.The Search Result Page takes parameters from drop down which is used in where clause in SP.Now what i am doing is I am populating the parameters in search page after checking the records for particular params exist in my db.

Its Like listing menus of items in restaurant and allowing the diner to choose from those.

So in order to that I am using one procedure to get paramaeters which shld be populated in search page and I am calling another proc which brings the actual result once search is carried out in search page into procedure which generates the parameter

Comment: Could you let me know how to insert values into temp table from stored procedure in Mysql

Answer (score 1):

- Could you let me know how to insert values into temp table from stored procedure in Mysql

  create temporary table <name> select * from <some results>
- Let me know how to count no of rows returned by one procedure in another procedure.

  select count(*) from <name>